# the css file will not load in my html webpage aplication

Tags: python, html, css, flask, pycharm

For some reason I cant seem to load my css file onto my flask website, I have tried many ways but for some reason it's not working. Here's all the files with the directory on the left hand side.

main.py
[image]

```
from flask import  Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE'] = False
@app.route("/home")
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

base.html
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
    {{super()}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css')}}" />
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

home.html
[image]

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% block title %}
Home Page
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Home Page</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

style.html
[image]

```
body {background-color:000000;}
```

Please note that 'main.py' is not inside of the folder of 'venv' but rather a sibling of 'venv', since it might look misleading

Comment: It would be less misleading if you just copy/pasted the text rather than a bunch of screenshots of code

Comment: ive added the code

Comment: Did you clear your browser's cache?

Comment: yes i did, didn't work